# Why selects LayoutKind.Auto for reference types and LayoutKind.Sequential for value types?

Tags: c#, clr

Here is the problem I am having. 
   [**CLR via C#, Third Edition**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735627048) says "You should be aware that Microsoft’s C# compiler selects LayoutKind.Auto for reference
types (classes) and LayoutKind.Sequential for value types (structures)."  What's the difference between [LayoutKind.Auto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) and [LayoutKind.Sequential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) ? Why does CLR can improve performance by arranging the fields of  a type ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's about performance?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler might be able to improve cache performance by arranging fields close together which are often accessed together (e.g. within a loop) so they end up in the same cache line.

**Update**: Another bigger optimization potential is the alignment of the members. For example `byte` can be 1 byte aligned while `int` is usually 4 byte aligned. So considering:

```
byte b1;
int i1;
byte b2;
int i2;
```

You would potentially waste 3 bytes of space when aligning the ints to 4 byte:

```
b1  0  0  0
i1 i1 i1 i1
b2  0  0  0
i2 i2 i2 i2
```

By reordering to

```
i1 i2 b1 b2
```

the compiler can reduce the waste:

```
i1 i1 i1 i1
i2 i2 i2 i2
b1 b2  0  0
```

So only 12 instead of 16 bytes needed.

It depends on the used CPU architecture wether or not this brings performance benefits though. Most 32bit RISC processors like their data 32bit aligned for example.

Comment: Yup.  Perf is automatic, it uses the CPU cache better.